# Maximize a target number by optimizing a weighting vector

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to maximize the number N_ent through a 1x42 weighting vector (weight).

`N_ent` is calculated with the following function:

```
N_ent <- exp(-sum((((solve(pca$rotation[])) %*% t(weight))^2)*
  (pca$sdev^2)/(sum((((solve(pca$rotation[])) %*% t(weight))^2)*
  (pca$sdev^2)))*log((((solve(pca$rotation[])) %*% t(weight))^2)*
  (pca$sdev^2)/(sum((((solve(pca$rotation[])) %*% t(weight))^2)*(pca$sdev^2))))))
```

Though it looks quite complicated, the equation works fine and supplies me with `N_ent = 1.0967` when equal weights of 0.0238 (1/42 = 0.0238) are used.

Further, none of the weights may be below -0.1 or above 1.

I am new to R have struggled to use both the `optim()` (ignoring my constraints) and `constrOptim()` functions, encountering the error

> Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be of length 1

when `optim()` was used and

> Error in ui %*% theta : non-conformable arguments

when `constrOptim()` was used.

Any help on how to set up the code for such an optimization problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I use `nloptr` package and function for optimization with constraints. Please include an example dataset `pca` so I will write down the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not sure how to upload the data but it is a 42x42 matrix and all elements are between -1 and 1 if that helps? Alternatively, perhaps I could somehow send you the data set?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) thread.

Comment: The dput command yielded output that was too large to copy from the console so I wrote it to this csv file, hope it works. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga99tgt1q7a5rz4/pca.csv?dl=0

Comment: Could you please give some detail about the problem you are solving - is it scientific or real-life problem. What is behind this entropy maximization?

Comment: Its a financial project which uses Principle Component Analysis (hence pca) in order to calculate uncorrelated returns. Consequently, entropy is a measure of portfolio diversification and the optimisation calculates the weights that maximise diversification. The methodology comes from Muecci (2010) if you're interested. http://www.master272.com/finance/GQ_docs/Meucci_10b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution using library `nloptr`.

```
library(nloptr)

pca <- dget('pca.csv')
#random starting point
w0 <- runif(42, -0.1, 1)
#things that do not depend on weight
rotinv <- solve(pca$rotation)
m2 <- pca$sdev^2

#function to maximize
N_ent <- function(w) {
  m1 <- (rotinv %*% w)^2
  -exp(-sum(m1 * m2 / sum(m1 * m2) * log(m1 * m2 / sum(m1 * m2))))
}

#call optimization function
optres <- nloptr(w0, N_ent, lb = rep(-0.1, 42), ub = rep(1, 42),
                 opts = list('algorithm' = 'NLOPT_LN_NEWUOA_BOUND', 'print_level' = 2, 'maxeval' = 1000, 'xtol_rel' = 0))
```

You can view result by `optres$solution`. For your particular problem I find `NLOPT_LN_NEWUOA_BOUND` algorithm giving best result of 42. You can view all available algorithms by `nloptr.print.options()`.  Note that `_XN_` in the names of the algorithms indicate these that do not require derivatives. In your case derivative computation is not that difficult. You can provide it and use algorithms with `_XD_` in the names.

Comment: I'm trying to add an inequality constraint to this but keep getting the error: `Error: nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint returned NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS`. Would it be possible to give me the format for that too? The constraint is A* w - B >= 0, where A=`matrix(runif(42,0.5,3), nrow=1, ncol=42)` and B is a constant.

Comment: You should use argument `eval_g_ineq` which takes function such that in the solution `g(w) <= 0`. So it should go something like: `g <- function(w) B - A %*% w`.